# Why is "react-native link some-native-module" a lottery?

Tags: react-native

I love React Native, mostly. Have been using it since 0.22. Currently on 0.35.

But why does linking native libraries act like a lottery? I rarely get it to work on the first shot, and the things that break are often completely different things.

Every RN upgrade is a pita. Here is what I usually do:

1. npm i react-native@0.35
2. `react-native upgrade`   (answer yes on every question to replace files)
3. insert my stuff in info.plist  (it got replaced..)
4. reinstall pods
5. relink all native modules
6. hold my breath and try `react-native run-ios`

Most of the times the above does not work. But it does work when I compile the app from within XCode.

The journey from here to a working `run-ios` is often long and frustrating. It involves the following:

1. unlink all native modules with `react-native unlink xyz`
2. manually remove header search paths the unlink didn't remove
3. `rm -rf node_modules`
4. `yarn`
5. product/clean from within XCode
6. install pods
7. link native modules

Sometimes the above works. Mostly it doesn't work. Usually some native modules ends up in the build error section when I run from `react-native run-ios`. Running from XCode works as usual.

The native modules ending up in the error section are not the same every time. I have also had some of the native modules "shipped" with RN error out. (RCTGeolocation, RCTActionSheet, RCTWebSocket)

Next "level" of solution (when I can't get the above) to work is this:

1. `react-native init nextAppAttempt`
2. copy code, assets, .babelrc, etc to the new folder
3. `yarn`
4. link all modules
5. install pods

I have had some success with the above, but the I have the pita of renaming the app to the real name and re-connecting to my GitHub repo.

Here are the native modules that I'm linking:

```
react-native link react-native-fs && \
react-native link react-native-camera && \
react-native link react-native-code-push \
react-native link react-native-permissions && \
react-native link react-native-image-resizer && \
react-native link react-native-mixpanel && \
react-native link react-native-maps && \
react-native link react-native-svg &&
```

- What's the deal here?
- Does this work for others?
- Are there flaws in my process? (I hope so)

Comment: Not exactly related, but I'll affirm that I always need to run `react-native run-ios` multiple times before the "No bundle url present" error goes away.

Comment: Gosh, can someone show me some lights here. really obnoxious issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had any of the above problems in a couple of months. I suppose it has to do with one of the recent RN upgrades. Today I upgraded from 0.45 to 0.47 with no issues whatsoever.

Could it be that something is fixed in RN and these problems are gone? I sure hope so.